# Are DLC achievements/trophies unlockable in a LAN game?

Tags: achievements, red-dead-redemption

I would like to play through the two DLC packs with a friend (Outlaws to the End and Legends and Killers) and I'm just wondering how many (if all or none) of the achievements/trophies can be unlocked in a LAN game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [True Achievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/) it looks like you will be able to complete all the achievements/trophies through LAN on Outlaws to the End (with the right amount of skill and patience) but **not** on Legends and Killers.